# SQL UNION with ORDER

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-order-by, union

What's wrong with this statement? I get the following errors:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

```
(SELECT TOP 1 dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date AS Date1, dbo.ZERORATES.Zero_Rate AS Rate1
    FROM dbo.ZERORATES
    WHERE dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date < '2013-05-16'
    ORDER BY dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date DESC)
UNION
(SELECT TOP 1 dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date AS Date2, dbo.ZERORATES.Zero_Rate AS Rate2
    FROM dbo.ZERORATES
    WHERE dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date > '2013-05-16'
    ORDER BY dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date ASC)
```

Comment: You want the first and the last value of maturity date, you can use the MIN and MAX functions to retrieve these values.

Comment: You can use `OVER()` and `PARTITION BY` then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to embed your queries in a select

```
select * from
(SELECT TOP 1 dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date AS Date1, dbo.ZERORATES.Zero_Rate AS Rate1
    FROM dbo.ZERORATES
    WHERE dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date < '2013-05-16'
    ORDER BY dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date DESC) as T
UNION
select * from
(SELECT TOP 1 dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date AS Date2, dbo.ZERORATES.Zero_Rate AS Rate2
    FROM dbo.ZERORATES
    WHERE dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date > '2013-05-16'
    ORDER BY dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date ASC) as T
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael, that does exactly what I need

Answer (score 1):

A UNION can Only have one order by which should only be in the last select also, a subquery can only have 1 column, change it to below:

```
SELECT TOP 1 dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date AS Date1, dbo.ZERORATES.Zero_Rate AS Rate1
    INTO #Temp1
FROM dbo.ZERORATES    
WHERE dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date < '2013-05-16'  
ORDER BY dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date DESC
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date AS Date1, dbo.ZERORATES.Zero_Rate AS Rate1
    INTO #Temp2    
FROM dbo.ZERORATES    
WHERE dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date > '2013-05-16'    
ORDER BY dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date ASC

SELECT * FROM #Temp1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM #Temp2
```

Comment: This doesn't do what I want though. I need the 2 days closest to the one specified there. This statement gives the first date in the table and the first date greater that the one specified.

Comment: @Michael: If you need the 2 days closest to the one specified there, then your original query is wrong.

Comment: If you want the closest from above and the closest from below, then OK.

Comment: Yes, the closest from above and the closest from below

Comment: Hmmm, weird, i've tested this query and it will give you the closet from above and the closest from below?

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY is invalid in views EDIT (ONLY in SQLServer)*unless SELECT TOP is specified* /EDIT.  Try ordering your result set after joining your tables.

Answer (score 0):

UNION can only have one ORDER, to get the top and bottom values you could use MIN and MAX

```
SELECT MAX(dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date) AS Date, dbo.ZERORATES.Zero_Rate AS Rate
FROM dbo.ZERORATES
WHERE dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date < '2013-05-16'
GROUP BY dbo.ZERORATES.Zero_Rate

UNION

SELECT MIN(dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date) AS Date, dbo.ZERORATES.Zero_Rate AS Rate
FROM dbo.ZERORATES
WHERE dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date > '2013-05-16'
GROUP BY dbo.ZERORATES.Zero_Rate
```

Comment: Just thought above won't work with multiple zero rates, might help you find an answer though. Maybe TOP 1 in addition to this...

Answer (score 0):

If there are no more than 1 row for every date, this will do:

```
SELECT z.Maturity_Date AS Date
     , z.Zero_Rate AS Rate
FROM
    dbo.ZERORATES z
        JOIN 
        (   SELECT MAX(dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date) AS D
            FROM dbo.ZERORATES
            WHERE dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date < '2013-05-16'
        UNION  
            SELECT MIN(dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date) AS D
            FROM dbo.ZERORATES
            WHERE dbo.ZERORATES.Maturity_Date > '2013-05-16'
        )
    AS maxmin
        ON z.Maturity_Date = maxmin.D
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant solution using `OVER()` and `PARTITION BY` but I'm not near a SQL-Server now to check.